# AngularJS - $watch and $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Having a hard time understanding $watch. I'm using it with a timer to increment a value - attempting to prompt a user after five seconds if they'd like to continue. If they select 'Cancel', then the timer stops counting.

Fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/nicktest222/VuuEK/4/

```
// Increment with $timeout
$scope.counter = 0;
$scope.onTimeout = function () {
    $scope.counter++;
    mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);
};
var mytimeout = $timeout($scope.onTimeout, 1000);

// Watch
$scope.$watch($scope.counter, checkTime);

function checkTime() {
    console.log($scope.counter);
    if ($scope.counter === 5) {
        var check = confirm('Do you want to continue?');
        if (check === false) {
            $scope.stop();
        }
    }
}
```

The checkTime function fires once on page load, I was hoping it would fire every increment as the $scope.counter variable is changing every second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$watch` takes an angular expression, this is what you want:

```
    $scope.$watch('counter', checkTime);
```

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Jason's answer, you can have a `$watch` on any variable of any scope since the parameter is just a string, so inside your controller, you can have a watch on `$rootScope` as well!

`$scope.$watch('counter', ...)`

`$rootScope.$watch('rootCounter', ...)`